# Two Edittext validations

Tags: android

I have two edittexts on single screen with one having max length 11 n other as 12.

Now I want following validations on these two edittexts.

1.Value of only 1 edittext should be passed on to next screen.This is mandatory..Value of only one must be passed to next screen.
2.If user started entering into any edittext then he should be forced to enter min 11 or 12 digits into respective edittexts.

This validation is to be done on button click on the screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `EditText onChangeListener` to recalculate the number of characters every time the user enters any text. Every time the `onChangeListener` is triggered for either of your EditText widgets, count the number of characters and enable or disable the Button that moves onto the next screen based on the character counts.

Answer (score 1):

check the following :
xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:maxLength="11"
    android:ems="10" >

</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
android:text=""
android:visibility="invisible"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
android:text=""
android:visibility="invisible"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText3"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:ems="10" />
```

and Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText et1,et2,et3;
Button btn;
TextView tv1,tv2;



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    et3.requestFocus();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    addListenerOnTextChangeEt1Text();
    addListenerOnTextChangeEt2Text();
    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {            
            if(!hasFocus){
                tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {            
            if(!hasFocus){
                tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(et1.getText().toString().length()<11 || et2.getText().toString().length()<12 ){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "check both edittext data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(et1.getText().toString().length()==11 && et2.getText().toString().length()==12){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Show next Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.v("Error","");
                    }
        }
    });
}
private void addListenerOnTextChangeEt1Text(){
    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int et1StringLength=et1.getText().toString().length();          
            Log.v("et1StringLength","--->"+et1StringLength);
            int num=11-(et1StringLength);
            if(et1StringLength<11){
                tv1.setText("Enter"+num+"Characters more");                 
            }
            else if(et1StringLength==11){
                tv1.setText("Correct");                 
            }
            else{
                Log.v("Error","");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}   
private void addListenerOnTextChangeEt2Text(){
    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int et2StringLength=et2.getText().toString().length();          
            Log.v("et2StringLength","--->"+et2StringLength);
            int num=12-(et2StringLength);
            if(et2StringLength<12){
                tv2.setText("Enter"+num+"Characters more");                 
            }
            else if(et2StringLength==12){
                tv2.setText("Correct");                 
            }
            else{
                Log.v("Error","");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}
```

and Follow this link to pass value to the next intent : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811030/how-to-pass-edittext-value-to-another-activitys-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:maxLength="11"
```

and

```
android:maxLength="12"
```

in xml file for respective edittext fields.

And to pass the value to next activity. You can use intent.

In first activity:

```
String s = myEdtxt.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextAct.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("My Value", s);
startActivity(i);
```

You can retrieve it in second activity as:

```
String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("My Value");
```

Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can Validate using `setError` Property Of EditBox
**mUserNameView** is my edittext
and
**mUserName** is a string in which i am taking the editText value to perform validation

```
 mUserNameView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mUserName = mUserNameView.getText().toString();



    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUserName)) {
        mUserNameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));

    } 
if (mUserName.length() > 13)
{

mUserNameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_notValid));
}


R.string.error_field_required
R.string.error_field_notValid
```

are defined in the string in values folder in resources

Adjust the login according to your need. I have given the code sample how to validate in code. and error messages(whatever you specify in String file) are generated in a very beautiful manner on the particular edit box,