# How to pass edittext value to another activity's edittext?

Tags: android

My project's requirement is : edittext value is first entered by user and that same value will be visible in another activity's editext , which should be read only..

Comment: whether you used bundle?

Comment: whatever comes your mind you are just asking not even trying to use worlds best search engine.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+pass+editext+value+to+another+activity%27s+editext%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs#client=firefox-a&hs=doe&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&channel=rcs&sclient=psy-ab&q=How+to+pass+editext+value+to+another+activity%27s+editext+in+android&oq=How+to+pass+editext+value+to+another+activity%27s+editext+in+android&gs_l=serp.3...5120.10689.0.10943.11.11.0.0.0.0.130.1207.1j10.11.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.EDHYD1Xa5Aw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.bmk&fp=d0854ba4402a6161&biw=1252&bih=610

Comment: @viewPagerSpecialist : Absolutely right.. Have you search or try this question? Before asking the question please  do some R&D work on that..

Answer (score 8):

You can pass it using Intent's putExtra() method. try this way,

In First Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( FirstAcvity.this, SecondActivity.class ); 
intent.putExtra ( "TextBox", editText.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in second activity, use following code,

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
String text = i.getStringExtra ( "TextBox","" ); 
// Now set this value to EditText 
secondEditText.setText ( text ); 
secondEditText.setEnable(false);
```

Comment: ok.i am trying this .both editext is same which is"Drop back ID" , in first activity value entered by user and when switch to next activity value will be received by same editext and read only.

Answer (score 1):

get the value of edit text by

```
String text = edit_text.getText.toString;
```

then pass it to other activity like

```
intent.putExtra("text", text);
```

In that activity get it onCreate through bundle like

```
Bundle extras = getExtra().getIntent();
String text = extras.getString("text");
```

now set this value in your edittext like

```
edit_text2.setText(text);
```

modify this code according to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send N number of data from one activity to other activity like below :

**Sneder :** Current.java

```
Intent values = new Intent(Current.this, Destination.class);
//values.putExtra("KEY","VALUE");
values.putExtra("USER_NAME",user_name);
startActivity(values);
finish();
```

**Receiver :** Destination.java

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lucifer's answer you could use a TextView in the second activity:

First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( FirstAcvity.this, SecondActivity.class ); 
intent.putExtra ( "text", editText.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
tv.setText(i.getStringExtra("text"); //tv is the TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically its not a big deal to pass edittext value to textview present in other activity just follow 2steps....

***PROCESS***

1. get two Activities(java classes)
2. in first Activity take editview
3. in second Activity take textview
4. dont forget to create a button and set Onclicklister to it
5. code the step2 in first activity inside button onclicklisten
6. now code the step3 in second activity
7. now run the code

   ((where "name" is indicated as a token to verify so maintain same char in both activities))

**STEP1**

1.Mainactivity.this//(Activity **from where** you should get the value)

```
EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra ( "name", ed1.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

**STEP2:**

2.Main2activity//(Activity **to where** you should get the value)

```
Textview textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Bundle bb;
bb=getIntent().getExtras();
textview.setText(bb.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public EditText var_name; 

var_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_id);

publc void function_name(){
    Intent i=new Intent(this, class_name.class);
    String s=this.edittext_var_name.getString().toString();
    i.putExtra("var_name","s");
    startActivity(i);
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help full for you.

This code for second activity where you want to show the Data from First Activity.

```
 String mUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("LinkingWord");
 editTextURL.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("LinkingWord"));
```

Don't forget to call EditText ID

```
  EditText editTextURL = findViewById(R.id.edit_url);
```

Easy Peasy

HappyCoding