# Can I send data string to another activity without move another activity?

Tags: java, android

Example I will send data from edittext to second activity without move another activity

Comment: If you won&#39;t move how is this Activitiy is going to alive ?? Or if you want send some data back to previous Activity then you should look for startActivityForResult() or Broadcast.

Comment: Is this question similar to yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811030/how-to-pass-edittext-value-to-another-activitys-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` to pass data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this data in **Shared Preferences** or **SQLite** then access it from the 2nd activity if you don't want to pass it via **Intent**